# Selenium - Web element reference not seen before

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

So I'm try to make a webscraper that detects every directory in this link : https://coursevania.courses.workers.dev/[coursevania.com]Python%20for%20Data%20Science%20and%20Machine%20Learning%20Bootcamp/

and then in each directory to get the name of every file in the directory itself, and return to the main page, I used a rather inefficient approach, is there a better way of doing this using selenium?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


# Step 1: Print all the names of every file in the directory
def mainpage():
    browser.back()
    browser.back()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(r"https://coursevania.courses.workers.dev/[coursevania.com]Python%20for%20Data%20Science%20and%20Machine%20Learning%20Bootcamp/")
time.sleep(2)
elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mdui-text-truncate")
for i in range(len(elements)):
    browser.get(r"https://coursevania.courses.workers.dev/[coursevania.com]Python%20for%20Data%20Science%20and%20Machine%20Learning%20Bootcamp/")
    time.sleep(2)
    elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mdui-text-truncate")
    element = elements[i]
    print(element.text[11:].strip(" ."), "------------------------------", sep="\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    element.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    files = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mdui-text-truncate")
    for _file in files:
        print(_file.text[17:].strip())
    print("------------------------------", "", sep="\n")
    mainpage()
    time.sleep(4)
```

The output format is as follows:

```
Directory Name
------------------------------
filename1
filename2
filename3
...
filenamenth
------------------------------

Directory Name
------------------------------
...
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the request posts return json format that you can use to iterate and print off the names. Not sure what exactly you want, but you can follow this:

```
import requests
import urllib.parse

url = 'https://coursevania.courses.workers.dev/[coursevania.com]Python%20for%20Data%20Science%20and%20Machine%20Learning%20Bootcamp/'

jsonData = requests.post(url).json()

files = jsonData['files']
output = {}
for each in files:
    directory = each['name']
    print (directory)
    print("------------------------------")
    output[directory] = []
    root = 'https://coursevania.courses.workers.dev/[coursevania.com]Python%20for%20Data%20Science%20and%20Machine%20Learning%20Bootcamp/'
    linkParse = urllib.parse.quote(directory)

    link = root + linkParse + '/'
    jsonData = requests.post(link).json()


    for file in jsonData['files']:
        fileName = file['name']
        print (fileName)
        if fileName not in output[directory]:
            output[directory].append(fileName)
    print("------------------------------", "", sep="\n")


print (output)
```

**Output:**

```
1. Course Introduction
------------------------------
1. Introduction to the Course.mp4
1. Introduction to the Course.vtt
2. Course Help and Welcome.mp4
2. Course Help and Welcome.vtt
3. Course FAQs.html
3.1 Py_DS_ML_Bootcamp-master.zip.zip
------------------------------

10. Python for Data Visualization - Pandas Built-in Data Visualization
------------------------------
1. Pandas Built-in Data Visualization.mp4
1. Pandas Built-in Data Visualization.vtt
2. Pandas Data Visualization Exercise.mp4
2. Pandas Data Visualization Exercise.vtt
3. Pandas Data Visualization Exercise- Solutions.mp4
3. Pandas Data Visualization Exercise- Solutions.vtt
------------------------------

11. Python for Data Visualization - Plotly and Cufflinks
------------------------------
1. Introduction to Plotly and Cufflinks.mp4
1. Introduction to Plotly and Cufflinks.vtt
2. Plotly and Cufflinks.mp4
2. Plotly and Cufflinks.vtt
------------------------------

12. Python for Data Visualization - Geographical Plotting
------------------------------
1. Introduction to Geographical Plotting.mp4
1. Introduction to Geographical Plotting.vtt
2. Choropleth Maps - Part 1 - USA.mp4
2. Choropleth Maps - Part 1 - USA.vtt
3. Choropleth Maps - Part 2 - World.mp4
3. Choropleth Maps - Part 2 - World.vtt
4. Choropleth Exercises.mp4
4. Choropleth Exercises.vtt
5. Choropleth Exercises - Solutions.mp4
5. Choropleth Exercises - Solutions.vtt
------------------------------
....
```

Comment: I haven't dabbled with panda yet or urllib, is there a way without these? like in selenium?

Comment: Yes, but it'll be much slower. I'd strongly suggest learning pandas (technically it doesn;t even need to be used here. I just used it to normalize the json into a table to iterate through. Sort of over kill, as you can just iterate through the json response.

Comment: I took pandas out. But the urllib.parse needs to be used to turn the text into the parsed url link to go get the file names from the link.